# If the sum of the first n terms of an Arithmetic Progression is equal to $n^2 + 3n$

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

If the sum of the first n terms of an Arithmetic Progression is equal to $n^2 + 3n$ then the first term of the Arithmetic Progression is[image]
I tried to solve this question by putting sum of of $n^th$ term of an Arithmetic Progression that is $(n÷2)(2a+(n-1)d)$= $n^2+3n$ but won't end up with an answer.please help me.

Comment: Well, taking $n=1$ gives....

Comment: You appear to be confusing "arithmetic sequence" with "geometric" sequence.  Your $n^th$ is for a geometric sequence..  The general form for an arithmetic sequence is $a+ nh$.

Comment: @user247327:  OP was giving formula for *sum* of arithmetic sequence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking $n=1$ we see that $S_1=a_1=4$.

Answer (score 1):

From your formula we get $$\frac{n(2a_1+(n-1)d)}{2}=n^2+3n$$ for $$n\neq 0$$ we get
$$2a_1=2n+6-(n-1)d$$ so...?

Comment: You left out ÷2 from OP's formula

Comment: Thank you!! Corrected!

Comment: The question is asking about the value of a by this method I got only the value of a in terms of n which will not solve my question as I can't put this value anywhere to solve the question.

Comment: Ok, then take $$n=1$$, then you will get $$2a_1=8$$